# Is there are any way to emulate key press in tmux

Tags: keyboard, command-line-interface, tmux

In Vim it's possible to emulate key press by defining what keys to press automatically in the vimrc file by `autocmd`.

```
autocmd VimEnter * wincmd w
```

So, is it possible to do something like this with tmuxrc ??

My end goal is to use replace the use of up and down arrow key's with any other key

Comment: As an example, I have `bind '#' select-pane -l` in my .tmux.conf so I can press
`prefix + #` to switch to the last pane I was in. Check out the `tmux
list-keys` in the terminal to see what possibilities there are.

Answer (score 0):

As an example, I have `bind '#' select-pane -l` in my `.tmux.conf` so I can press `prefix + #` to switch to the last pane I was in. Check out the `tmux list-keys` in the terminal to see what possibilities there are.

Credit: [mattb](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14467607/mattb)